# How to solve this complex limit $ \lim_{N \to \infty} \arg \left( \frac{1}{Nj+1}\right) $

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

How to solve this limit
$$
 \lim_{N \to \infty} \arg \left( \frac{1}{Nj+1}\right)
$$

The prove that I have seen is using that the $\arg$ of a quotient is the diference beetween the num and den i,e:

$$
\arg \left( \frac{1}{Nj+1}\right)=\arg \left( 1\right)-\arg \left( Nj+1\right)= 0-\arg \left( Nj+1\right)=-\arg \left( Nj+1\right)
$$

Then how $A \to \infty$ then I can ignore the $1$(This do not convice me very much) and I get 
$$
= -\arg \left( Nj\right)
$$ 
So $\lim_{N \to \infty}-\arg \left( Nj\right)=\lim_{N \to \infty}-\arg \left( j\right)= -90^{deg}$

But in this last line I can really forget de N?, and why?

Comment: You should really be thinking geometrically, with a picture drawn in your imagination. The points you’re looking at are $(1,N)$ in the plane, and the line joining them to the origin is getting more and more nearly vertical. So the answer (before the minus sign) is $90^\circ$ and $-90^\circ$ when you take account of the sign. Of course the “$N$” vanishes after you’ve performed the limiting process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, assuming that $\text{j}^2=-1$:

$$0^\circ=0\le\arg\left(\frac{1}{1+\text{N}\text{j}}\right)=\arg\left(1\right)-\arg\left(1+\text{N}\text{j}\right)=0-\arctan\left(\frac{\text{N}}{1}\right)\le2\pi=360^\circ$$

And:

$$\lim_{\text{N}\to\infty}\arctan\left(\text{N}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}=90^\circ$$

Answer (score 0):

We could first simplify :

$$\frac1{Ni+1}=\frac{1-Ni}{1+N^2}\implies \arg\frac1{1+Ni}=\arctan(-N)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}-\frac\pi2$$

In degrees, the above would be $\;-90^\circ\;$

Comment: I do not understand How you get the second equality. @DonAntonio

Comment: @JuanMuñoz It is the definition of argument when the real part of the complex number is positive...